# Automatically moving all mails belonging to same conversation thread to external folder

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Hi I have Exchange Server 2007 setup with some users with their own inbox. Since this is all related to office conversations I want to move all the incoming and outgoing mails belonging to same conversation thread to disk folder (any folder on his machine say `D:\Conversation1`).

I am able to let user create separate disk folder for each conversation and let him move first mail in conversation to this folder. So that is not the problem now.

Also I have written a web app which when provided the conversation ID returns the corresponding disk folder path.

However now what I want is to process all incoming & outgoing mails and auto move them to the disk folder corresponding to their conversation thread. I found two possible ways:

- **Write Outlook plugin** which when user logs in will intercept all incoming mails and outgoing mails find their conversation id, send it to web app I written and move them to the disk folder path returned by my web app.
- **Using EWS:** I could write a service for client machines which will ask for user login and based on that login cred it will connect to Exchange server using Exchange Server Webservices (EWS) and will then do the same thing as above. However here it will require to periodically poll / ask Exchange Server to check if their are any new mails sent / received through by the user who provided the login credentials. In outlook plugin I need not do such periodic requests - I could just write code on new incoming / outgoing mail handlers.

**Q.** Is there any better approach to achieve this through EWS than as explained above.

**Main Q.** What I find wrong with both above approaches is that - my functionality is same for all mails accounts / users. So why need user to log in just for movement of mails. Can I write something like Exchange Server Tasks ( **- a server side code instead of client side code as it was the case with both above approaches**) which will **continuously process** all mails (**from all mail accounts** configured on Exchange Server) find their conversation IDs and with the help of my web app move them to the corresponding disk folder.

**Details that you may ignore**

- I have Outlook 2010 configured for users.
- I have a repository setup that will manage storage of mails in folder. Yes this repository will be own its own machine - not on the exchange server. But eventually it will be on hard disk, so referring them as "disk folder" is still no wrong.
- Also you can think of that web app as a part of repository handling. So it runs on repository machine. Just didn't mentioned above to reduce details and focus on which approaches available and preferable - simple and clean.

Comment: To remove any ambiguity, please edit your question and name every folder on disk 'disk folder' and every folder in Exchange 'mail folder'.

Comment: Where is that web app running? Why a *web* app? Where are these disk folders located? Please add some info about your network structure.

Comment: IIRC there are such things as *push notifications* where Exchange notifies you about new mails etc. You are definitely right that you should attempt to write a background program that requires no user intervention. That program would run on your server and thus **not** use Outlook (sysadmins justly don't like Outlook running on the mail server).

Comment: @JanDoggen actually all above mentions of folders meant to be a disk folder, no Exchange mail folder here. Anyways updated questions to include what u want in last two bullet points. And thank u to point me out to push notifications - wasnt aware of that.........

Comment: ........But I think with them too, I will get push notifications only for one user account ([this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/emeamsgdev/archive/2012/12/20/ews-push-notification-sample.aspx) push notification handler sample app requires  both uname and pwd). Now if I had to move mails from 100 such user accounts, do I need to keep running 100 such instances of push notification handlers all time? And also is there any Java implementation of such push notification handler available?